# Date display with javascript

Tags: javascript

my instructions are to Include a function defined via a function
expression that displays the current date and time in an h2 at the top of the
page when the page is opened. Add an id=”dateDisplay” to the h2. Include
a self-invoking function that changes the color of the date text that was
printed by the first function.

Im a bit confused on how to accomplish this. I tried to do a function expression to display the date but i get nothing shown and no errors. I tried to do a body onload to call the function but that result in a console error of function not defined.

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <h2 id="dateDisplay"></h2>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
var d = new Date();
var x = function dateDisplay(){
    document.getElementById("dateDisplay").value = d;
}
```

I'm really confused by the instructions. What exactly am I suppose to do to get this in working order.

edited: I had an error with my link to my js file. The issue now is I get console error document.getElementById... is null weather i use innerHTML or value or .innerText

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call your function, and use `.innerText` and not `.value`. Note `value` is only for `input` elements.

```
var d = new Date();
var x = function dateDisplay(){
    document.getElementById("dateDisplay").innerText = d;
}

x();
```

Comment: why does this work in jsfiddle, but not when i upload to my server? or do a preview view in komodo IDE?

Comment: @kronis72 Make sure you are running the JavaScript after the `dateDisplay` element is loaded.

Comment: I had an issue with my link to my js file, but your code example i get a console error that states document.getelementbyid is null

Comment: @kronis72 Then it's because your JavaScript is being ran before the element is being loaded. You can prevent that by placing the code inside `window.onload = function(){ ... }`. JSFiddle does that automatically by default. [For example](http://jsfiddle.net/y1v1o94q/).

Answer (score 1):

you must use this code :
**Javascript**:

```
var d = new Date();
var x = function dateDisplay(){
document.getElementById("dateDisplay").innerHTML = d;
}
x();
```

To "display data" in HTML, (in most cases) you will set the value of an `innerHTML` property.after this change you must call `x()` function .
**and you hava to use this after `dateDisplay` element loaded**.

Comment: while this works in jsfiddle this does not work when on my server.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the .innerHTML method like so:

```
var d = new Date();
var x = function dateDisplay(){
    document.getElementById("dateDisplay").innerHTML = d;
}
x();
```

You also forgot to call the function x

Answer (score 0):

call function directly more prefer than assign to variable function

```
var d = new Date();
dateDisplay();
function dateDisplay(){
   document.getElementById("dateDisplay").innerHTML = d;
}
```